# Is it possible to unset private_tempstore values?

Tags: 8, sessions

I have a block that creates a private_tempstore value (which I understand works exactly like PHP sessions).

How do I unset that value.

This is the code I am using for the block.

```
class SsoSessionBlock extends BlockBase {
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function build(){
        $value = 'dav';
        $session = \Drupal::service('user.private_tempstore')->get('achva_sso');
        $session->set('name', $value);


        return [
            '#type' => 'markup',
            '#markup' => $this->t('The output of super SsoSessionBlock block.'),
        ];
    }
}
```

I saw [this method](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21PrivateTempStore.php/function/PrivateTempStore%3A%3Adelete/8.2.x), but I am not sure how I am supposed to use it.

I tried the following code, but I get an error.

```
namespace Drupal\achva_sso\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\Core\Routing\TrustedRedirectResponse;
use Drupal\user;


class SsoController extends ControllerBase{
    public function ssoLogout(){

        $session = \Drupal::service('user.private_tempstore')->get('achva_sso');
        PrivateTempStore::delete('name');

        if(isset($session)){
            $status = $session .' is logged in';
        }else{
            $status = 'is logged out';
        }
        return[
            '#type' => 'markup',
            '#markup' => '<p>' . $status . '</p>' ,
        ];



    }
}
```

How do I unset a value I previously set?

Answer (score 5):

> I have a block that creates a private_tempstore value (which I
>   understand works exactly like PHP sessions).

No, both are for different use cases.

Private tempstore is used mainly for larger quantities of data. To store a single value it would be too much overhead. Instead use the session object of the current request:

```
$request = \Drupal::request(); 
// in a class inject RequestStack and $request = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest();
// or get the request as controller parameter, see link below
$session = $request->getSession();

// set a value
$session->set('my_value', $my_value);

// unset a value
$session->remove('my_value');
```

This is the official Drupal 8 way to store session data and since you've tagged the question with `sessions` this probably what you are looking for, see [Access session data through the Request object](https://www.drupal.org/node/2380327)

Comment: Hey,few questions, 
1.  Where do I get the set function now that I have removed the ` \Drupal::service('user.private_tempstore')->get('achva_sso');`
2.  I have added the folowing namespace `use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;` in the block file, than inside the build function I wrote this code: `  $request = \Drupal::request();
        $session = $request->getSession('name');` and than I return the $session var. I keep getting an error

Comment: this is the error
`Recoverable fatal error: Object of class Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session could not be converted to string in Drupal\Component\Utility\Xss::filter() (line 67 of core\lib\Drupal\Component\Utility\Xss.php).`

Comment: The code in the answer works as it is. Dependency injection is a different issue and you can include this as a TODO comment for later when you want to test the class.

Answer (score 3):

`delete()` is the method to delete a value in the store.

```
$session = \Drupal::service('user.private_tempstore')->get('achva_sso');
$session->delete('name');
```

`'name'` is the value passed as first argument in any call to `set()`.

You don't use [`PrivateTempStore::delete()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21TempStore%21PrivateTempStore.php/function/PrivateTempStore%3A%3Adelete/8.9.x) since it's not a static method and it would throw errors or warnings, if called as static method.

As side note, user.private_tempstore is a deprecated service. Instead, the tempstore.private service should be used. (See [User module's user.private_tempstore and user.shared_tempstore services moved to core](https://www.drupal.org/node/2935639) for more details.) In the latest Drupal 8.5.x version, the service is marked as deprecated directly in the [user.services.yml](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21user.services.yml/8.5.x) file.

```
class: Drupal\user\PrivateTempStoreFactory
arguments:
  - '@keyvalue.expirable'
  - '@lock'
  - '@current_user'
  - '@request_stack'
  - '%tempstore.expire%'
deprecated: 'The "%service_id%" service is deprecated. You should use the ''tempstore.private'' service instead. See https://www.drupal.org/node/2935639.'
tags:
  - { name: backend_overridable }
```

It should also be better to use dependency injection: A class extending `BlockBase`, or `ControllerBase`, can implement the `create()` method to load new dependencies.

Comment: Hey, Thank you for your answer. Tried this but the tempstore is not deleted. I created a new page with the `$session->get('name')` . I go to the page with the delete, than go back to the page with the `get` and I still see the `name` value...

Comment: Keep in mind that when a user logs out, or logs in, the tempstore is changed. If, for example, you set a value when the user is logged-in, and delete the same value after the user logged out, that value is still associated to the user account.

Comment: o.k I undestand. thank you... now I see I asked the wrong question... I need to store a session for an anonymus user... thank you!

Comment: @kiamlaluno thanks your answer was very useful to me.